# Saving sign in info in php

Tags: php, cookies

After the user signs in to the site, I save two cookies, one for user_ID and another for the password, and when every page loads, it checks the password ,,
How can I avoid saving the password like this? anyone who opens page info can see all cookies values? and if I saved the user_ID only, setting the user_ID cookie's value by browser tools may also changes the user?

Comment: Once a user is authenticated you have no need to store their password. Don't store it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the password in a cookie (please never store a plain text password anywhere - ever), you can create a session key and store that in a cookie.

Which is exactly what php [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), [session_start()](https://www.php.net/function.session-start), etc. is for.

Managing your own sessions when facilities have already been provided for you is just a recipe for a big headache.

To make use of sessions you can simply call `session_start()` at the top of your file.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo session_id(); //output the current session id
?>
```

The docs are pretty clear on all the ways sessions and session variables can be used, I suggest spending some time reading them and/or some of the many tutorials you can find through your favourite search engine.

Comment: please explain more about creating a session key.

Comment: added a bit more info

Comment: Then I shall save the session_id in a table, where I link it to the user_id, and when every page loads, it gets user info from session_id?